# How to load test client/server based redis,twisted and iPhone application

Tags: python, ios, redis, twisted

I would like to simulate connections of thousands of clients at the same time to my server to see if it can handle it? I am just trying to use my iPhone and iPhone simulator to create connections however it is not a real time simulation. How can I do a load test?

Here is an example of my server code:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import defer

class STSFactory(Factory):
    def __init__(self,conn):
        self.conn = conn
        self.protocol = STSProtocol

class STSProtocol(Protocol):
    def log(self, message):
        print "%s: %s" % (self, message) 
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.log("Connection made")
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)
        self.log("Connection Lost")
    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def getUser(self,user):
        val = yield self.factory.conn.hgetall("user:%s"%user)        
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        cmd = data.split(':')        
        command = cmd[0]        
        arg1 = cmd[1]
        arg2 = cmd[2]
        if arg1 == "logon":
            self.getUser(arg2)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    import redis
    conn = redis.Redis(unix_socket_path='/tmp/redis.sock')
    factory = STSFactory(conn)
    factory.clients = []

    print "Server started"
    reactor.listenTCP(11000,factory)
    reactor.listenTCP(11001,factory)
    reactor.listenTCP(11002,factory)
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  The answer to the question you asked, "How do I load test my application with thousands of clients?" is answered "By hitting it with thousands of clients and measuring what happens."  If you wanted a more detailed or specific answer, you need to ask a more detailed and specific question.  The alternative, having someone build a load testing application for you in a SO answer, is not likely to happen.

Comment: I am not asking someone to write me a test application. I am wondering about how to load the server before going into production to see if it will handle the load or not. I am trying to load the system using iPhone simulator and I dont believe this is the right way. I'm just wondering if there are any software or tools that can be used by asking the experienced people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How and where are hosting your server? In a simple case you can use Siege from your local machine (siege the URLs that will be the majority of requests) http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home

You can also use service like Blitz.io http://blitz.io/ you can then load the service from different geographical areas (which makes huge difference in performance). There are many services like this just search for web load testing. I like Blitz because I use Heroku and it integrates nicely with it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a great tool for load testing, called [Locust](http://locust.io/). You can write test scenarios in python, it's scalable and even has a web-based GUI if you need that.